# Encrypted Windows laptop - Can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows without wiping everything?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, encryption

I have a laptop running Windows 7. The whole drive is encrypted with trucrypt. For various reasons I need to keep Windows on the laptop (software compatability etc).
Trouble is the laptop is INCREDIBLY slow. Just booting it up and performing everyday tasks takes a lifetime.
I want to resize the Windows partition and install Ubuntu for everyday browsing, etc. Is this possible without wiping the laptop? Do I need to decrypt it all first? And if so - how risky is it?

Many thanks in advance for your help!